# How can you reference a namespace declared outside the current namespace with the same name?

Tags: typescript, namespaces

Consider the following TypeScript:

```
export namespace Test {
    export const test = "test";
}
export namespace Wrapper {
    export namespace Test {
        export const value = Test.test; // "<script>".Wrapper.Test has no exported member 'test'.
    }
}
```

Due to the way TypeScript compiles to JavaScript, the second declaration of `Test` within `Wrapper` will create a new scope where `Test` will refer only to itself. The top-level `Test` is unavailable within that scope, at least according to the TypeScript type checker.

I'm generating the TypeScript from another language where this sort of namespace collision is no big deal. In TypeScript, however, it results in a compilation error. The application still runs, so this seems to be a TypeScript type checking issue and not a real JavaScript runtime issue.

Are there any known workarounds within TypeScript?

I've got a repro set up in a [Gluon issue](https://github.com/Tachyus/gluon/issues/47#issuecomment-324064763).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an alias to overcome the namespace collision:

```
export namespace Test {
    export const test = "test";
}

import _Test = Test;

export namespace Wrapper {
    export namespace Test {
        export const value = _Test.test;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I think I could codegen this, too, but should this really be a type checker issue? It seems to be valid JavaScript at runtime.

Comment: `namespace` is a TypeScript (not JavaScript) construct. It compiles into a function wrapper. Go ahead and compile it yourself to see what the actual JavaScript looks like. You'll see that the JS actually looks a lot like the above, and in fact has the same naming issues.

Comment: It seems that the TypeScript team are aware of this issue - see [this declined feature request for introducing a global scope reference](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/983) which was submitted by Anders Hejlsberg